# <select id="image-details-link-to" data-setting="link"> changing option for all posts

Tags: images

How can i change option value as 'file' for all posts?

```
<select id="image-details-link-to" data-setting="link">
<option value="file">Media file</option>
<option value="post">asd</option>
<option value="custom">Special address</option>
<option value="none">None</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/415648/edit) to provide more information. Where is this code snippet run? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In the option table `image_default_link_type` is the key for that setting. So you can change its value with filtering. Please see below example.

```
add_filter( 'option_image_default_link_type', function () {
  return 'file';
});
```

With this, `file` will be selected by default when you insert media attachment.

Comment: Hi Nilambar thanks but where should i put this code?

Comment: In theme's `functions.php` file.